# In the same column, compare each value with previous multiple values with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I'm working on a table looks like this. The actual dataset contains thousand of Guest_ID, and I'm just showing few sample lines here.

| Guest_ID | Visit_ID | Collection_time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | a178 | 2007-11-09 11:28:00 | 2.6 |
| 6 | a188 | 2007-11-10 20:28:00 | 6.6 |
| 12 | a278 | 2008-11-11 10:28:00 | 2.7 |
| 12 | a278 | 2008-11-11 11:38:00 | 3.2 |
| 12 | a278 | 2008-11-12 11:48:00 | 6.8 |
| 12 | c348 | 2009-10-12 11:38:00 | 3.8 |
| 15 | e179 | 2013-01-15 09:25:00 | 1.8 |
| 15 | e179 | 2013-01-15 10:26:00 | 1.6 |
| 15 | e179 | 2013-01-15 12:15:00 | 3.8 |
| 15 | e179 | 2013-01-17 09:25:00 | 3.6 |

What I'm trying to do here is to find out the values that had increased by at least 3 within the past 48hr, and these values need to be under the same visit_id. In this case, result should only return

| Guest_ID | Visit_ID | Collection_time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | a278 | 2008-11-12 11:48:00 | 6.8 |

I have some vague ideas of creating islands and gaps in SQL Server, but not sure how to approach it. Conceptually, for each value X, I need to extract all the previous value meets the conditions (within past 48hr AND under the same Visit_ID), then check if X - min(previous value) >= 3. And if yes, keep or label X as 1, and repeat the procedure.

I read a lot of posts like using `lag()` or `row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...)`, but still unsure about what to do. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please, **do not** post data as images, instead post _DDL & DML_ or _formatted text_ so others can copy/paste it and brings an answer to ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have been a good spot to use window functions with a date range specification. Alas, SQL Server does not support that (yet?).

The simplest approach might be `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.visit_id = t.visit_id 
        and t1.collection_time >= dateadd(day, -2.collection_time)
        and t1.collection_time <  t.collection_time
        and t1.value < t.value - 3
)
```

Or you can use `cross apply`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select min(t1.value) as min_value
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.visit_id = t.visit_id 
        and t1.collection_time >= dateadd(day, -2.collection_time)
        and t1.collection_time <  t.collection_time
) t1
where t1.min_value < t.value - 3
```

Comment: Don't you think it should be  `t1.value <= t.value - 3` as the OP says _"had increased by at least 3"_?

Answer (score 0):

I used a CTE to filter out the qualifying rows first and then just join it back up to the original table to grab those rows:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(Guest_ID int, Visit_ID varchar(10),   Collection_time datetime,   Value decimal(10,1))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
(6, 'a178', '2007-11-09 11:28:00',  2.6),
(6, 'a188', '2007-11-10 20:28:00',  6.6),
(12,    'a278', '2008-11-11 10:28:00',  2.7),
(12,    'a278', '2008-11-11 11:38:00',  3.2),
(12,    'a278', '2008-11-12 11:48:00',  6.8),
(12,    'c348', '2009-10-12 11:38:00',  3.8),
(15,    'e179', '2013-01-15 09:25:00',  1.8),
(15,    'e179', '2013-01-15 10:26:00',  1.6),
(15,    'e179', '2013-01-15 12:15:00',  3.8),
(15,    'e179', '2013-01-17 09:25:00',  3.6)


;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT MAX(Collection_time) MaxCollection_Time, Max(Value) - Min(Value) DiffInValue ,Visit_ID 
    FROM #tmp
    GROUP BY Visit_ID
    HAVING Max(Value) - Min(Value) >= 3
    )
SELECT t1.*
FROM #tmp t1
INNER JOIN CTE t2 on t1.Visit_ID = t2.Visit_ID and T1.Collection_time = t2.MaxCollection_Time
```